# 301 redirect via .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect all http page visits to https via a 301 redirect. 
Unfortunately the code in my .htaccess is not working properly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The main page [www.besserbrauer.de](http://www.besserbrauer.de) works, but none of the links on the site work anymore (only a blank page is shown when clicked). Any ideas? Note: I removed the .htaccess for now, but if you want to see what happens, I can upload it again for a while.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will force the browser to browse to https

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bessenbrauwer\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.besserbrauer.de/$1 [R,L]
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you! The main goal is to avoid duplicate content so our Google ranking doesn't drop. Your solution sounds like both the http and https sites will be visited by users then

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem with your code: Blank page, as soon as I click any of the website links ...:(

Comment: @JörgIversen do you see `https` in the URL bar?

Comment: Yes, but what I want to prevent is that Google still shows the http sites. Some of them are still shown when I google for keywords.

Comment: @JörgIversen Google needs some time to crawl all the websites, maybe within a few days it will change. I cannot say how long exactly.